# javascript prototype call method in a "Click" event

Tags: javascript, methods, call

I'm a little bit new in javascript prototype. I have trouble of calling a method within an event handler, it just kept saying "not a function". Could someone help me to point out what did I do wrong. I appreciate for any comments.Thanks. Here's my code

```
var oneStepCheckOutEnhance = Class.create();
oneStepCheckOutEnhance.prototype = {
   test: function Test() {       
      alert('test');
   },

   observeShippingMethod: function () {
       $$('dl.shipment-methods input').invoke('observe', 'click', function  () {
          this.test(); //Keep saying Uncaught TypeError: this.test is not a function            
       });
    },    
};
```

Here's how I called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var onStepEnhance = new oneStepCheckOutEnhance();
   onStepEnhance.observeShippingMethod();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the scope you're calling it is the first function closure it hits (i.e. the anonymous function that's handling the click), not the object.  You can bind it to the parent object like so:

```
var oneStepCheckOutEnhance = Class.create();
oneStepCheckOutEnhance.prototype = {
   test: function Test() {       
      alert('test');
   },

   observeShippingMethod: function () {
       $$('dl.shipment-methods input').invoke('observe', 'click', function  () {
          this.test();         
       }).bind(this); // right here, it binds the handler to the parent scope.
    },    
};
```